# Multiple MySQL versions using Homebrew on macOS giving Error - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mysql, mac

I am trying to set up multiple MySQL versions using Homebrew. I have already been using MySQL 8.*, which is running fine. However, due to some old project requirements today, I have installed another version of MySQL (5.7). Now when I switch to mysql@5.7, it gives me the following error.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

##### Please have a look at the following details

Both versions of MySQL are installed using **Homebrew**.

###### MySQL 8.* (latest) location

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33/*
```

###### MySQL 5.7 location

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.42/*
```

Their symlinks are in `/usr/local/opt/*`

I have modified **homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist** as follows.

###### Original

```
...
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
        <string>--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

###### Modified

```
...
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
        <string>--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql57</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/mysql57</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

To switch between versions, I have set up an alias in `~/.zhsrc`

```
# MySQL Version Switching
mysqlv() {
    brew services stop mysql
    brew services stop mysql@5.7
    brew unlink mysql mysql@5.7
    brew link --force --overwrite $1
    brew services start $1
}

alias mysql57="mysqlv mysql@5.7"
alias mysql80="mysqlv mysql"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"
```

Later I set **password** for the **root** user to none with the following query.

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost='';
```

Now when I run the alias `mysql57`, it switches and links the MySQL version but when I try to login to `mysql -uroot` it gives below error.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
```

Can anyone help me to fix the issue so I can switch and use any version of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is related to the fact that both mysqld instances seems to be configured to use the same socket file */tmp/mysql.sock*. If the socket file is not correctly removed when one of the instances is stopped, it might cause issues when the other instance is started.

There are different options to get around this issue:

- Using TCP to connect to the mysqld server instead of using sockets
- Using docker containers for the mysql server instances. If you're doing web development I highly recommend taking a look at [ddev](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which makes it extremely easy to set up different versions of mysqld.
- Configuring different socket files for the instances by modifying the mysqld config for at least one of the instances:

```ini
[mysqld]
socket=/tmp/mysql2.sock
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the cause. I have checked, and the ‘sock’ file is removed when I stop MySQL 8.0 

I think the last option of setting different sock files would be easier. However, I am not an expert and am unaware of where to update or define it for MySQL 5.7 (newly installed). Can you guide me on it?